# Linphone trouble

Tags: video, linphone

I have a problem with Ubuntu and Linphone. I want to communicate with the TDoor Communication System (2n sip System /audio and video talk). With Windows I can and it works fine, but in Ubuntu only audio works.

In Windows I had to set the setting video enable H264 by Cisco systems and with this it's fine, but this option is not working in Ubuntu. The slider will be back to off after setting it to on. Turn it to On, then are you sure you want to install, answering with yes, then something downloading (really too fast) and then the Slider will be moved from On to Off again.